# Multiresolution modifier creates unusable geometry

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution

I am trying to apply the Multiresolution Modifier to a simple geometry, but the end result is unusable and not what I wanted at all.

Before modifier:

[image]

[image]

After modifier:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you want more edge loops around your round-rectangle object, mostly edge loops that intersect with vertexes of the holes; the geometry might have the right shape but blender really likes quad shapes (four vertexes per face).
However, without being able to see what settings your multires modifier had I cannot help.

With the default settings and a similar shape to yours, I had no problem using the modifier, so would prefer more information to help.
[image: Multires on rectangle booleaned object]